What are the best possible space weapons?
I am again asking about space weapons. This time, I am asking about the best weapons of these three categories: Missiles, Lasers, and Kinetics. I am fitting these on a heavy starcruiser capable of outputting up to 60 terawatt hours annually. Heat is not a problem unless it immediately melts the weapon. Also, I would prefer all warheads to be thermonuclear. I want the best possible balance between cheap, and BOOM. I am aware there are superior alternatives, but I need a ship to transport and protect the maintenance staff for the ship's large and power-hungry payload: An "Einstein-Rosen Civil Engineering Device" (portable wormhole machine, which works by means classified to the general public)
PS. I read the eternally useful Atomic Rockets but my knowledge is very limited. In other words, keep it simple please.
PPS: By hard science, I mean handwavium Is highly illegal, except where it Is necessary, No outright violating physics, just loopholes, and pushing physics to the limit.

Define best. The best vehicle to carry potatoes from the field to the market 50 km away is not the best vehicle to win the 24 hours of Le Mans.

VTC:Needs More Focus but I also agree with the previous VTC:Needs More Details. Please take the time to read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], and [ask] to better understand this site. (a) You're allowed to ask one and only one question. Asking about three different weapon types is asking three questions. (b) Asking for the "best" of anything is story-based (as in VTC:Too Story-Based) because you can write the conditions of your story to rationalize anything as "best" (even a sling shot). (c) If you can't explain how you'll judge a best answer, the question isn't ready to post.

@user111403 Woo-hoo! I've personally used micro- and picoparsecs, so... Hallelujah! Viva la revolución!

Also. I've removed the [tag:hard-science] tag and invited the mods to remove the question header. Please read the tag wikis. Answers that don't meet that tag's requirements are subject to deletion. It is NOT a "give me the highest quality answer!" shortcut and it's definitely not related in anyway to your PPS (not at all...). As a final note, if you feel compelled to qualify your use of a tag in your post, you either didn't read the tag wiki, don't care about the tag wiki and want to use the tag in a way it's not meant to be used, or you don't understand the tag. Don't redefine tags.

What is this spacecraft's mission?  Who/what are the anticipated opponent/s?  As currently written, this is like asking "what is the best weapon for a person?" without specifying whether they are fighting wasps, rodents stealing their food, human muggers, human soldiers, armoured vehicles or ground attack aircraft.  This is worse, though, because we don't know any characteristics of the spacecraft or opponent/s - mass, delta-v, acceleration, sensor capabilities, computing capabilities...

This could be a fun question - but OP - May I suggest you read this: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/261344/world-building-knowledgebase-how-to-write-good-military-world-building - You have not told us about what sort of threat your space vehicle is expected to encounter (which is the biggest determining factor here)

I concur with the opinion this question needs serious improvement. For example, what is the acceleration and/or maximum velocity of a "star cruiser"? It's kinda important, because if either is high enough, it will be able to evade missiles like it's a hummingbird. What is the propulsion type: reactionless or chemical reaction? What is the fuel for both, either? what is the energy budget of a "star cruiser" for armaments, be it projectile, beam or missile launchers? Is the combat in deep space possible or it's  near-planetary space? Or is it solar-system scale? What are the detection systems?

@AcePL the propulsion is Nano Electrokinetic Thruster Arrays (NEKA Drive) AKA EVs in space. Also, I'm still designing the vehicle, I'm not to sensor arrays yet. But I have stated the power output to be 60 terawatt hours annually Combat will be similar to The Expanse, at hundreds of thousands of kilometers.

Could you please add the salient details to the body of the question. Comments are ephemeral - and future readers shouldn't need to read anything but the question itself in order to understand the requirements and constraints.

Ok Ok, I get the point, I'll ask a different question later, with more details

@AspiringAuthor Standard SDI satellite was calculated to need about 1MW of steady output of power source just for normal operations, add couple hundred of MW for weapons. Assuming 100kT star cruiser (=CVN-78), just basic power needs is 200MW, which is 3% of your annual budget. Moving it is way more expensive (say 25000MW, average for relocation/combat) - another 370%, and where's the power for combat systems? (reference: F9 heavy at liftoff generates about 26GW). The Expanse's combat physics are laughably simple and riddled with errors.

What is the best weapon for an underwater company of musketeers? You disband them and buy a submarine and some torpedoes.
The best weapon for the hard science space battleship is to strip it for parts and replace it with a few tiny missile tenders and hundreds of free floating missiles.
Space is fundamentally unlike earth, water, or air: there is no drag to make one big ship more eficient and nothing to push against to make a big hull or a big wing or big wheels a cheap way to keep from falling. A space ship is a missile. Anything you can put on a space ship you can put on a missile by definition. Anything science-based that doesn't need to be on or otherwise constrain a missile but does need to be on your space ship is wasted by building a superfluous crewed missile and attaching it to the armed missile. Anything that your space battleship would have that doesn't seem missile-like (such as a cannon) can be separated off and put on a missile in place of the warhead. Or in the case of a nuke-pumped laser, powered by the warhead. Thus making it cheaper, faster, more versatile in agregate, harder to detect, and more spread-loaded.
We can walk these factors back with Sufficiently Advanced Technology (magic with some technobabble welded on), such as a cloaking device, energy shields, a hyper efficient reactor/booster combination with a large minimum size, or a warp drive...  but reality is a notorious killjoy. Under real life constraints, space battleships are as implausible as their captains deciding the fate of the battle in an awesome space sword fight.
My suggestion would be, if your story is about the crew of a big warship, to not worry about it at all and just mix and match bits and pieces from your favorite parts of reality and pre existing fiction, tell the reader that the weapons you have described are, in fact, the best we can do, and let suspension of disbelief take care of the science.

This answer was written while the question was tagged as a request for Hard Science.

Burnside's Zeroth Law of space combat: Science fiction fans relate more to human beings than to silicon chips.

I'm well aware there are superior alternatives, but I do have my reasons: the ship is carrying a large and high matenince payload

This answer was flagged as low quality. Actually, it's very insightful and good advice for (OK, I can't avoid the pun) aspiring authors. The only thing missing is the formal declaration as a Frame Challenge. So, looks OK to me.

@AspiringAuthor "I'm well aware there are superior alternatives" then clearly you're not asking for "best".

@VLAZ I mean superior alternatives to crewed military spacecraft. a swarm of torch missiles will do far better in combat, I know.

The "best" alternative would be not an alternative - it would be the cheapest. Missiles are cheaper than a large craft full of crew with expensive training (regardless of the human cost). @AspiringAuthor Could you clarify what they're up against and what your expectations are? (in an edit to the question).

@Escapeddentalpatient. I mean in economic terms, what is the most dangerous weapon, for the least amount of money, in that category

@AspiringAuthor re silicon chips, I think there's a great sci-fi story out there waiting to be told about a few lonely missile tender operators on a tense secret mission way out in the dark, hunted by unknown enemies, with nobody in visible range even if they turned on the lights. Just rare point-to-point communication microbursts exchanging text messages with each other as they escort a huge mysterious cylinder with their flocks of nuclear missiles. I'm pretty sure that's not the story you want to write, but... I kind of want to write it now that I express it like that.

@gs Now I want you to write that... That would be pretty cool... However, what I'm going for is way different. Humans do human things* with alien tech (*steal and reverse engineer) Aliens steal the human testing ship to keep them from the secret of FTL, and Protagonist and Co. are sent to find out what happened, why, and to get the ship back. The United Space government knew something might happen, and armed the ship with the standard trio. It wasn't enough.

Rule, Britannia! Britannia rule the voids: Britons never never never shall be droids!

Kinetics.
Ever since the celebrated space naval battle between the lumbering FSS Saddymack and the nimble UNS Polytor, fought to a standstill in the stellar roadstead off Beta Draconis, has shown the viability of superpositioning gossamer tourettes when combined with transluminal double-stroke Beauforce guns, all capital ships, from starlet cruisers, to light, medium and heavy star cruisers, to mighty battell shippes, have carried multiple such batteries for the purpose of surprisingly effective point defense.
Million tonne star cruisers, the veritable stars of the cruising scene, are positively festooned with gossamer tourettes, grouped in the traditional four linear batteries. Such a linear battery consists of a dozen tourettes, each of them hosting quadruple geminated transluminal double-stroke Beauforce guns capable of throwing a hundred tonnes of subconic osmium projectiles per second at any target within a solid angle of almost six steradians.
The advantage of the superpositioning gossamer tourette is that it allows extremely fast and very precise gun laying, with an accuracy of one thousandth of an arc-second and a response time not exceeding a quarter of a picosecond, which in practice is actually faster than the fire control ultracomputers can even compute the targetting solution; we don't foresee any material improvement in gun targetting until the end of the 42nd century, maybe even the first half of the 43rd.
Although introduced by the Beauforce Weapons Systems more than four generations ago, the transluminal double-stroke Beauforce geminated gun has remained unsurpassed in close-defense roles. It's called a double-stroke gun because of its principle of operation: the gun first launches a collimated stream of inflatrons, about the thickness of an ordinary neverending quill, which create a tunnel of rarefied space; the second stroke throws a stream of 2⅕ lb osmium subconic projectiles at about 94,000,000 knots through the rarefied space tunnel, so that the effective transit speed to the target is about ten times the speed of light. When the projectile exits the tunnel and returns to normal space at one tenth of the speed of light it will hit the target with a release of energy equivalent to about 100 kilotons of TNT.
True, that is only if it hits the target; but here is where the fabulous rate of fire of the Beauforce transluminal double-stroke gun comes in handy. As a matter of fact, the principal limiting factor in the number and density of the linear batteries with which capital ships are equipped is the mass of the ordnance. A hundred tonnes per second is six thousand tonnes per minute! Even a million-tonne star cruiser can only carry enough osmium ordnance for fifteen minutes of fire or thereabouts.

Missiles.
A typical million-tonne star cruiser carries a mix of long-range restartable Jiffyman heavy missiles and short-range Battlehatchet missiles. The Jiffyman masses about a thousand tonnes, while the Battlehatchet is about four times lighter; but the Jiffyman is capable of multiple pre-programmed super-luminal flight phases, and its terminal maneuvering can extend to almost two minutes with accelerations of up to two thousand kilometers per second squared, whereas the Battlehatchet can only perform a single phase of superluminal flight and its terminal maneuvering capabilities do not exeed thirty seconds with a more modest maximum acceleration of only six hundred kilometers per second squared. Both types of missiles carry thermonuclear-pumped laser warheads capable of delivering about 9 petajoules of semi-directed electromagnetic energy, which is about 2 megatons of TNT equivalent. Of course, the Jiffymans carry four such warheads.
In principle, the mass budget allocated for the missile department on a million-tonne star cruiser is an impressive 250,000 tonnes, which could be divided ad libitum into Jiffymans and Battlehatchets as best suitable for the mission profile; but in practice nobody currently serving in the navy has ever begun a patrol with more than 200,000 tonnes of missiles aboard, and that was the battell shippe USN Hasart when it sailed out on its much criticised but ultimately successful mission of muscular diplomacy during the Second Crisi of Agga Dirh.

Lasers.
The thermonuclear-pumped laser warheads carried by the Jiffyman and Battlehatchet missiles have already been mentioned.
Most old-style star cruisers, as well as some starlet cruisers and certain elderly battell shippes are also equipped with four full arrays of fixed tenth-petawatt lasers for point defense, but their utility has been called into question by numerous critics, and newer naval units only have six to ten quarter-arrays, thus reducing mass requirements for the hypercapacitors in favor of mounting more and more Beauforce guns.
The venerable multicast Jane's Fighting Ships has been tracing the development of the wondrous new generation of peracapacitors for almost two decades, and most experts expect that full-petawatt fixed-defense lasers will be introduced for the next generation of capital ships when the new Naval Construction Budget will be finally approved.



+1 for Rule Brittania.

@TheDemonLord Until the American torch missiles start to give chase...

@AspiringAuthor ... which even starlet cruisers can evade by engaging semi-passive, static-kinetic defenses ("Caltrops launchers"), colloquially called by crew members "manure spreaders", acknowledging the same operating principle, as well as visual effect. It ejects several tons of sand, spreading it lightly on the path of incoming missiles. Size of the grain makes it impossible to detect in time and evade, but as it is very dense cloud (in terms of interplanetary space), missiles are sand-blasted, causing them to lose lock or straight up detonate.

@AcePL look up a torch drive, and the advanced principle known as, "turning and burning" then resume the chase. Oh, did I mention the 10kg antimatter annihilation warhead? Made fresh at mercury by SeeTee For Thee Inc.

@AspiringAuthor - I am familiar with the concept. And I prefer it's original name - Orion drive. And the answer is the same - the faster they go, the prettier the explosions once sh*t-spreader starts spewing c-ap.

I’m voting for a kinetic weapon. (1/2)mv^2 is your friend.
So something like high-powered rifle or 20mm cannon would be an excellent “space weapon”. All you need a hull breach and your enemy is space-dust.
No air = no resistance or slow down of the muzzle velocity.
No gravity = flat trajectory.
Small but fast mass = hard to detect or avoid.
You’d just need a recoil compensator (since Newton’s laws of motion are still in effect)

No, I want all three weapons, not just one.

Kinetics: Railgun slugs- shot far outside of a system, accelerated to c- recieving "course corrections" and "scatter" commands while beeing inbound. You want a observer in the system, that only corrects the shots fired, coming in.
Rockets? Yeah, they make for fireworks. But not like kinetics. They are slow - unless you energize them up to C with lasers- in which case you get -> Kinetics.
Lasers: Easily deflected and defended against. hard to keep together at a distance great as engine for -> rockets
